# Are questions regarding the language acquisition methods of famous individuals on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

We have several questions that fall in line with this topic: namely this question about [Cardinal Mezzofanti](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/2282/how-did-cardinal-mezzofanti-learn-foreign-languages?noredirect=1&lq=1), and this more recent question about [Celine Dion](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/3198/how-did-celine-dion-learn-to-sing-in-perfect-english). Are these questions on-topic? How can one determine if an individual is well-known enough to ask about here?

Answer (score 1):

I consider the current two examples (Mezzofanti, Celine Dion) as on topic. I doubt that we can establish a degree of "fame" that can serve as a threshold. Mezzofanti is fairly well-known in the polyglot community; there is at least one site that was named after him. Céline Dion is definitely famous, but I don't know whether we'll find anything about her learning process. However, "there is no information on x is not a valid close reason", as far as I know.